# What exception to throw to indicate child process freezed

Tags: c#, exception, freeze, child-process

**Question 1 - practical**

I run child process in my C# application using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Like the following:

```
Process process = new Process();

// ... StartInfo initialization here

int timelimit_ms = 30000;
process.Start();
if (!process.WaitForExit(timelimit_ms))
{
  // What exception to throw here?
  throw new Excpetion(
    "An executing method exceeded the time limit of " + timelimit_ms.ToString() + "ms");
}
```

I'm currently throwing `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`. But I don't sure it is the best choice. The child process is a simple command line utility. So the first question, what exception to throw in this situation?

**Question 2 - thoretical**

This is not the first time I ask myself about what exception to throw. And I don't know of a simple guidelines on how to pick a certain one. There are so much exceptions in C#, deeply inherited from one namespace to another. The second question, how to decide what exception to throw in a specific situation?

Comment: You could create your own exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, I'd throw a [TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx) as it describes what is happening

Theoretically, if a quick google / read of the docs doesn't throw up an exception that already describes what is happening then you can just extend Exception to generate a WeirdThingThatHappensSometimesInMyApplication Exception.

But it depends who or what is going to "read" your exception. If your exception isn't exceptional then maybe you should do things differently :-)

Answer (score 2):

how about a [timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx) exception?

Answer (score 2):

I would think about throwing [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) from the code. 
As states MSDN, this exception is:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

So the *caller* of the `function` or *consumer* of the `object` that runs and waits for the process will be notified about the fact that execution of the function failed.

If you want to be detailed about declaration of the failure reason, you can express it

- or in detailed message (if it's enough)
- or create yuor own custom exception derived from `InvalidOperationException` and populate it with additional data you may need outside from the caller.